# Positive definite matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having difficulties with a proof. I should prove that

> If $A^3=A+I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix), then $\det(A)>0$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: If you look at it this way $A^3-A-I=0$, so that it looks like a polynomial, that might help. Also note that $\det(A)$ is the product of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Your question title has a passing mention of positive definiteness, but the question body does not state that $A$ is positive definite. Although one can prove the problem statement without using positive definiteness, if you do require that $A$ is positive definite, please state it clearly in the question; otherwise, please change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ satisfies the polynomial $p(x) = x^3 -x - 1$ the eigenvalues of $A$ lie amongst the roots of $p$. $p$ has one positive root (roughly $1.32$) and a pair of conjugate roots. I am assuming $A$ is a real matrix so that the conjugate root pair occur together. The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues so $\det(A)$ is some product of the positive root and the conjugate root pair. It follows that $\det(A)$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Thank you, that helps, however, I am  not really sure how I should justify that the eigenvalues of A are the roots of the polynomial. Maybe I am just too tired because it has been a hard day today, but I can't think of any formal reason how to write it down. But again, thank you very much!

Comment: @user74200 Do you know about the minimal polynomial yet?

Comment: I think it was mentioned, however, it was not explained deeply. I am in the second semester of physics and we run through the mathematics very fast, since our school is known for trying to catch up the physics lectures so we could be able to use the mathematics needed for understanding it.

Comment: @user74200 The basic result you need to know is that the roots of the minimal polynomial are exactly the eigenvalues of the matrix. Since the minimal polynomial necessarily divides any annihilating polynomial, it follows that the eigenvalues of the matrix form a subset of the roots of any annihilating polynomial.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much for your help and for broadening my knowledge about linear algebra.

Comment: @user74200 You're welcome. I would recommend picking up an external reference for this stuff if your class is moving so quickly. Hoffman and Kunze covers this material quite well.